# Classic Asp Script to create ScriptManager control

Tags: asp-classic

I've a user control developed in .Net and I should be able to use this in classic Asp. I'm able to register that control as com component and create the control using syntax `Server.CreateObject(MyControl.MyControl)` but  the problem is I need to create `ScriptManager` control as well using the `server.CreateObject` to fulfill my requirement. So can anybody help me with the syntax for creating the `ScriptManager` control using the syntax `Server.CreateObject`.